# Kitchen give me some problems when i run kitchen setup

Tags: rubygems, chef-infra, vagrant

I'm trying to execute the **kitchen setup** but then an error happened

```ssh
kitchen setup
-----> Starting Kitchen (v1.1.1)
-----> Setting up <default-ubuntu-1204>...
       ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'busser' (>= 0) in any repository
       ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
           Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Connection timed out - connect(2) (http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
sudo: /tmp/busser/gems/bin/busser: command not found       
sudo: /tmp/busser/bin/busser: command not found       
>>>>>> Setup failed on instance <default-ubuntu-1204>.
>>>>>> Please see .kitchen/logs/default-ubuntu-1204.log for more details
>>>>>> ------Exception-------
>>>>>> Class: Kitchen::ActionFailed
>>>>>> Message: SSH exited (1) for command: [sh -c 'BUSSER_ROOT="/tmp/busser" GEM_HOME="/tmp/busser/gems" GEM_PATH="/tmp/busser/gems" GEM_CACHE="/tmp/busser/gems/cache" ; export BUSSER_ROOT GEM_HOME GEM_PATH GEM_CACHE; if ! sudo -E /opt/chef/embedded/bin/gem list busser -i >/dev/null; then sudo -E /opt/chef/embedded/bin/gem install busser --no-rdoc --no-ri; fi; gem_bindir=`/opt/chef/embedded/bin/ruby -rrubygems -e "puts Gem.bindir"`; sudo -E ${gem_bindir}/busser setup; sudo -E /tmp/busser/bin/busser plugin install busser-serverspec']
```

I have installed the busser gem

```ssh
gem list buss

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

busser (0.6.0)
busser-serverspec (0.2.5)
```

I'm really lost..!!

Comment: That error is on your VM. Does your VM have Internet access? If you're using VirtualBox, you probably have to enable shared networking. Stackoverflow is not the correct venue for bug reports, please use GitHub issues instead.

Comment: I'm sorry for my mistake...!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I made a more deep research  and I found that my internet connection was really bad and then when the guess machine tried to connect to [rubygems.org](https://rubygems.org/), this return a error connection timeout or refuted.

I downloaded busser gem and put it on my local repository, I entered to kitchen instance  and changed the gem source repository for my local repository and everything works fine.

Comment: @sethvargo, do you know how to configure o customize a gem source for kitchen instances from kitchen.yml file?